# php - Get cookies after setcookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

`Notice: Undefined index: posts_notification` while it's set.

```
functions.php :

add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_example' );
function my_setcookie_example() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['posts_notification'])){
        setcookie( 'posts_notification', 'value', time() + 60,COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}

print_r($_COOKIE['posts_notification'] );
```

I should refresh 2 time to get this value !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check cookie first.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['posts_notification'])) {
    print_r($_COOKIE['posts_notification'] );
}
```

Comment: i know but it should be defined after use setcookie

Comment: if you wanna get cookie value, firstly you need to set it, but maybe i don't understand what you want, tell me more about it

Comment: I don't need testing, because i know how to use cookie

Comment: I know too . but it's diffrent on wordpress  ! because we are setcooki after sent header !